Is it possible to run OS commands on worker nodes?
We currently receive gzipped csv files from source. We found it's more performant to unzip the files with a gunzip command before proceeding with the bronze loads.
To (somewhat) achieve parallelism, we create a thread for each file and begin decompressing. This is obviously only done on the driver node. We are using Databricks, and the cluster needs a minimum of 2 woker nodes. Is there any possible way to get these 2 other nodes involved with the decompression? This is a very time consuming step, especially with large historical batches, so was looking to see if we could speed this up at all by getting the workers involved, in addition to being more cost efficient as well.

You can misuse udfs.
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


@F.udf(returnType=StringType())
def decompress_file(file_name: Column):
    try:
        # code to download, decompress and upload the file
        return f'decompressed {file_name}'
    except Exception as e:
        return f'exception {e} while decompressing {file_name}'


file_list = ['1.csv.gz', '2.csv.gz', '3.csv.gz',]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[(f,) for f in file_list], schema='file_name: string')
df.withColumn('decompresion_result', decompress_file('file_name'))

NOTEs:

Assumes the input files are available on some external storage and not driver hard disk. If they are on driver then you will need to make them available on all worker nodes.
If the UDF implementation uses some non-standard/special libs then you'll have to install them on workers too.
In general implementing error handling in this is difficult.



We found it's more performant to unzip the files with a gunzip command before proceeding with the bronze loads.

I do not really understand this. If you say spark.read.csv('folder/with/lot/of/gzipped/csv/files', compression='gzip') it's going to decompress the files and load them, distributing the work to workers. Perhaps more efficiently then you decompressing them and then running spark.read.csv('folder/with/lot/of/csv/files').

so our files are coming in so large (whole other issue) that we get out of memory issues when trying to decompress/read into spark directly
